# Is it possible to make an ecs ContainerDefinition reusable in cloudformation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, ecs-taskdefinition, nested-stack, amazon-ecs-sidecar

Currently I'm having an ECS TaskDefinition with one ContainerDefinition running in my ECS Cluster. This is all defined in an cloudformation .json file and working fine. Now I would like to add a sidecar pod to this application, which is running an hashicorp vault agent and is pushing data to an efs, to be read by the applicaiton on start.

This setup is currently working fine. My problem is now, that I have multiple Backend Applications, where the vault-agent should be added and I would like to make the ContainerDefinition of the sidecar pod reusable. I thought about using for example a nested stack, but as I understood I actually need to define a full reources and not only a part of a resource (in this case the second ContainerDefinition of a TaskDefinition).

Is there any way to build this as a reusable stack?

Comment: The only way I imagine these wants are possible is by using AWS CDK Constructs similar to the example given at https://constructs.dev/packages/@aws-cdk-containers/ecs-service-extensions/v/2.0.1-alpha.90?lang=typescript